# valgrind & C++ : building std::string from character buffers

Tags: c++, valgrind

Simple C++ / valgrind question I'm hoping somebody can help out with.

When running valgrind against the following code, I get two possible leaks related to std::string :

```
==10325== 17 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==10325==    at 0x402569A: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==10325==    by 0x40CFD05: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x40D0B10: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x40D0CF5: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x804872B: main (test.cc:9)
==10325== 
==10325== 17 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==10325==    at 0x402569A: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==10325==    by 0x40CFD05: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x40D0977: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x40D17AC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x40D1C7F: std::string::append(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x40D1D63: std::string::operator+=(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==10325==    by 0x804879D: main (test.cc:11)
```

While it wouldn't be too much work to suppress them, and the code seems straightforward enough to me, I'd like to be sure I'm not missing something obvious here before I try to convince valgrind that I know what I'm doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char buffer[8192];
        sprintf(buffer, "ABCD");
        std::string str(buffer);
        std::string str2 = "";
        str2 += str;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terminating the program by calling `exit()` is not really an orderly shutdown, it basically aborts the program at the current place. Therefore `str` and `str2` are not destroyed before program termination and valgrind picks up on that.

When you exit the program normally by just returning from main, the destructors for `str` and `str2` should get called and the reported "memory leaks" should go away.

Answer (score 7):

Note also that if you are using `libstdc++` (the standard c++ library for Linux and some BSDs), you should compile your program with `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW`, to disable `std::string` memory pool optimizations, which look like leaks to valgrind. Remember to turn that back off for your release builds :-).